# How to download a file from multiple Linux machines using WinSCP or batch script?

Tags: linux, batch-file, script, download, winscp

I need to download a specific file from 40 different Linux machines.
How can I achieve using single script?
I tried `WinSCP.com /script=script.txt`
Here the limitations is only one session can me make from one script. I can’t mention multiple open session.

I need a technique which will log into all the servers one by one and download the file and place to my local drive.

Comment: In case somebody using Linux has this question and reaches this page. Look for "parallel-slurp" from the Debian/Ubuntu package "pssh"

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple `open` commands in WinSCP script file. If what you mean was that you want to specify multiple `open` commands, without need to repeat the download commands (`get`) for each server, you can use [parametrized script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#arguments). Start with WinSCP article
[Upload to multiple servers / Parametrized script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_multiple_servers).

```
open %1%
get /remote/path/file.txt
exit
```

And in your batch file:

```
winscp.com /script=script.txt /ini=nul /parameter sftp://user1:password1@server1.example.com/
winscp.com /script=script.txt /ini=nul /parameter sftp://user2:password2@server2.example.com/
rem Etc...
```

To further limit the repetitions you can do:

```
set DOWNLOAD_FROM=winscp.com /script=script.txt /ini=nul /parameter 
%DOWNLOAD_FROM% sftp://user1:password1@server1.example.com/
%DOWNLOAD_FROM% sftp://user2:password2@server2.example.com/
rem Etc...
```

---

Similarly for upload:
[Uploading file to multiple FTP sites automatically](https://superuser.com/q/1519450/213663)

Comment: Thank you Martin Prikryl.